# Probability that $n$ white balls are drawn before $m$ black balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question:**

Balls are randomly withdrawn, one at a time without
replacement, from an urn that initially has
N white and M black balls. Find the probability
that n white balls are drawn before m black balls,
$n\leq N ,m \leq M$.

**The answer:**

[image]

Now I have a a lot of issues with this answer and I will try to summarize.

**First:**

I don't understand what the $m+n-1$ should represent.

**Second:**

The answer says $m$ or less; shouldn't it be just less than $m$? since if were to have at least $n$ balls then the largest number of black balls we are to have is simply $m-1$.

**Third:**

Overall as you've probably already noticed, I simply do not understand this solution whatsoever, for instance, why did we have to consider *at least* $n$ balls; shouldn't we just care about getting *exactly* $n$ balls before $m$?

**Fourth:**

Following up my third point I propose another solution where the experiment ends once we withdraw our $n^{th}$ ball before having withdrawn our $m^{th}$ ball; this can be done in a number of ways:

$n$ white; $0$ black

$n$ white; $1$ black; and so on until:

$n$ white; $m-1$ black

so the solution in this case should be:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{ \binom{N}{n} \binom{M}{i}}{\binom{M+N}{n+i}}$

Now obviously if you were to substitute with values for $n, m, N, M$; the results will be different.

What I want is to understand the author's answer first; then understand why my answer is incorrect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q1: To understand the significance of $~(n+m-1),~$ consider an actual example.  Suppose that $~n=3,m-6,~$ and consider what happens after the $~8$-th ball is drawn.  At this point, **exactly one** of the following two events must have occurred: Event-1 : there were at least $~3~$ white balls drawn.  Event-2: there were at least $~6~$ black balls drawn.  So, after the $~8$-th ball is drawn, you are guaranteed that there will be *exactly one winner*, white or black.

Comment: Q2: Yes, you are right.  The solution has a typo.

Comment: Q3: No: consider the concrete example of $~n=3,m=6,~$ from the first comment.  It is (**harmlessly**) assumed that $~8~$ balls will be drawn, **regardless** of whether (for example) there has already been $~3~$ white balls drawn.  This (**artificial**) strategy is designed to facilitate the approach in the documented solution.  So, assuming that *white wins*, in the first $~8~$ draws, there could have been $~3~$ white balls drawn, $~4~$ white balls, $~cdots, ~8~$ white balls drawn.

Comment: Re last comment, the reason that I described the approach as **harmless** is that if there are $~3~$ white balls drawn **before** the $~8$-th ball is drawn, continuing to draw balls until $~8~$ balls are drawn **can not change who wins**.

Comment: **Comment 1:**
I think there might be a typo; perhaps you meant $m=6$ not $m-6$.

**Comment 4:**
My approach yields $1.56$ :)  ; for $N=25; M=20; n=3; m=6$.

Comment: So obviously there's something wrong with my approach; only I don't know what it is.

Comment: $0.9364798559...$

Comment: Again; with $N=10; M=8 ; n=3; m=6$ my approach yields $1.63$

Comment: It just hit me.  Your approach is invalid because you are overcounting.  Take the specific case of $~n=3,m=6~$ and consider the two events : Event 1: The first three balls are white.  Event 2: Three out of the first four balls are white.  These events are **not** mutually exclusive, because you could have had the first three balls white, and the fourth ball black.  So, your approach is invalid, because of overcounting.

Comment: Your alternative approach, while **not recommended** is do-able.  The remedy is to re-design your strategy so that the events are mutually exclusive.  For example, with $~n=3,m=6,~$ to consider the event that the contest is over after **exactly** four turns, **and not before**, two things must happen.  There must be exactly $~(m-1)=2~$ white balls drawn in the first three *rounds*, and there must be a white ball drawn specifically in round 4.

Comment: I see; given that we now are concerned with the order with which the balls were withdrawn, the probability should be calculated using factorials instead of the binomial coefficient right?

Comment: No.  In the specific situation of $~n=3,m=6,~$ where you are calculating the probability that white will win on the 4th turn (but not before), the computation is $$\frac{\binom{N}{2} \times \binom{M}{1}}{\binom{N+M}{3}} \times \frac{N-2}{N+M-3}.$$  The first factor above represents the probability of there being exactly $~2~$ white balls in the first $~3~$ draws.  The second factor is the probability of drawing a white ball on the fourth draw.

Comment: Thanks a lot; your new formula works and I made an answer with the new summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is:

$$\sum_{i=n}^{m+n-1}{(\frac{\binom{N}{n-1} \binom{M}{i-n}}{\binom{M+N}{i-1}} \frac{N-(n-1)}{N+M-(i-1)})}$$

For explanation read the comments on the question.